# Display in data.frame a conditional row count by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am struggling with creating a new variable in my data.frame. I apology for the question title that might not be very clear.  I have a database that looks like this:

```
obs    year    type
 1     2015     A
 2     2015     A
 3     2015     B
 4     2014     A
 5     2014     B
```

I want to add to the current data.frame a column (freq2015) that gives the number of rows by type for 2015 and report the result disregarding the considered year so long as the type is the same. Here is the output I am looking for:

```
obs    year    type    freq2015
 1     2015     A         2      (there are 2 obs. of type A in 2015)
 2     2015     A         2      (there are 2 obs. of type A in 2015)
 3     2015     B         1      (there is 1 obs. of type B in 2015)
 4     2014     A         2      (there are 2 obs. of type A in 2015)
 5     2014     B         1      (there are 1 obs. of type B in 2015)
```

I know how to add to my `data.frame` the number of rows by type by year using `dplyr`:

```
data <- data %>% 
     group_by(year, type) %>% 
     mutate(freq = n())
```

But then, for year=="2014" the added column will display the count of 2014 rows by race instead of that of 2015.

I know how to isolate into a new `data.frame` the number of rows by race for 2015:

```
data2015 <- dat[dat$year==2015,] %>% 
         group_by(type) %>% 
         mutate(freq2015 = n())
```

But I don't know how to add a column (with the count of rows by race for 2015) for the entire data.frame conditional on the type being the same (as shown in the example). I am looking for a solution that would prevent me from explicitly using the "type" variable modalities. That is, I don't want to use a code telling R: do this if type==A, do that otherwise. The reason for this restriction is that I have far too many types.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It may be easier to produce a summarised data frame of the counts of years and types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `group_by` using only `type`, you can sum the rows when `year == 2015`.

```
data %>%
    group_by(type) %>%
    mutate(freq2015 = sum(year == 2015))

Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
Groups: type [2]

    obs  year   type freq2015
  <int> <int> <fctr>    <int>
1     1  2015      A        2
2     2  2015      A        2
3     3  2015      B        1
4     4  2014      A        2
5     5  2014      B        1
```

Comment: This is the fastest method. It also works when the variable to be summarize is a factor instead of an integer, which is good news :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the data table we could do:

```
setDT(df)
setkey(df,type)
df[ df[ year==2015, .(freq2015=.N), by = type]]
```

Result:

```
     obs year type freq2015
1:   1 2015    A        2
2:   2 2015    A        2
3:   4 2014    A        2
4:   3 2015    B        1
5:   5 2014    B        1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `left_join()`, as follows:

```
temp <- data %>% 
    filter(year==2015) %>%
    group_by(type) %>% 
    summarize(freq = n())#  %>%
data <- data %>% left_join(temp, "type")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `base R` using `ave` (without any external packages) and it is reasonably fast as well.

```
df1$freq2015 <- with(df1, ave(year == 2015, type, FUN = sum))
df1$freq2015
#[1] 2 2 1 2 1
```

Comment: Indeed, it works perfectly fine. It is however not as intuitive (for me at least, who is new to R) to use a command dedicated to calculate average for counting. How would you explain this code with a sentence? (I'm asking because I can see that it works but I don't really understand what I am doing)

Comment: @Elixterra  What do you mean by `dedicated to calculate average`? The `ave` is a generic function but by default it gives the average though you can specify the `FUN` with any other function like here i used `sum` to sum the logical index (`year == 2015`) grouped by 'type'.

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought `ave` was meant to calculate averages only. I didn't know it was a generic function whose default action is to calculate average but that could be redefined. You proved me wrong. Thank you for your reply. I now understand what the code is doing :)